# Dark matter a medium for light propagation

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, dark-matter, aether

Is dark matter a candidate to fill void left by [luminiferous ether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) as a medium for light travel?

Comment: no. the michelson morley experiment shows that there exists nothing with the attributes of ether and special  relativity has made everything consistent. what void?

Comment: What is to prevent dark matter from being  hypothesized as a medium of propagation?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't believe light can propagate in a vacuum?

Comment: @user56930 the fact that light propagates equally well in areas with very little DM as it does in areas with high concentrations of DM. That tends to indicate it has no role as a medium of propagation. Otherwise density changes would produce optical effects

Comment: Thanks. Does sound travel at varying speeds through a bell jar as air is pumped out of it?

Comment: By the way in answer to a previous comment I believe light travels in a vacuum.

Comment: @user56930: Sound waves travels at different velocities depending on their frequency and amplitude at all thermodynamic conditions.

Comment: I believe it. Yea

Answer (score 18):

No.

There is no void left by the lack of an aether. The very notion of aether should serve as a warning as to how catastrophically analogical reasoning can fail. "Water waves are in water, sound waves are in air, therefore there *must* be *something* in which light propagates." This is flawed logic, and decades of physics were arguably hindered by adhering to it.

In fact, *any* material medium for light would contradict the beautiful result of [Michelson and Morley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment), showing that the speed of light does not depend on velocity with respect to some material's frame. This invariance is in fact now at the very heart of modern physics, and is the basis for relativity, which has been verified in innumerable experiments.

[Dark matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) is, according to the leading theories, some form of matter that is basically normal *except* that it essentially doesn't interact via the electromagnetic force. As such, it is actually a poor candidate for explaining anything to do with light, even if there were something that needed explaining.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm sure the void I speak of is the void in my own.  understanding. Suffice to ask only: is there anything to prevent the hypothesis that dark matter might propagate anything as a medium. Perhaps my question is not a fair question.

Comment: Things can only propagate stuff they interact with. Dark matter's sole reason for existing is that we see evidence of stuff that interacts via gravity and essentially nothing else. So it can have gravitational effects, but e.g. gravitational waves, like light, don't need a medium to propagate in.

Comment: "Water waves are in water, sound waves are in air, therefore there must be something in which light propagates." ... There is something in which light propagates: the electromagnetic field. It just happens to be a field that is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Dark matter  may propagate sound, i.e. pressure waves of some type. In general it has been hypothesized to fit the gravitational  orbits of galactic clusters, so dark matter  is not something permeating all space uniformly.

Comment: @user1247 the electromagnetic field is actually a varying electric and magnetic field with energy and momentum, not permeating all space either.

Comment: I'm simply asking an isolated question. Is there anything to prevent the hypothesis that dark matter as it is currently conceptualized might propagate anything?...just received your kind answers. Thanks

Comment: @anna v, that is completely wrong, as you should know, by definition of *field*, by any knowledge of the Standard Model, and by experimental fact of vacuum polarization, casimir effect, etc.

Comment: In the usual understanding the field *does* permeate all space, but it may have value zero in much of it, indicating that there is "no electric field" in the language used in introductory courses.

Comment: Yes, and light is understood to be ripples in the EM field that permeates all of space. It is of course a Lorentz invariant field in accord with the Michelson Morley experiment.

Comment: @user1247 I was talking of classical fields which is the background of the question. Not of the QFT vacuum, which respects Lorenz invariance of course .

Comment: @anna v, classical fields are not the background of the question. The question is about nature generically, which we know is not classical.

Comment: @user1247 Sorry but this board is for answering specific questions  so the questioner can learn something "Is dark matter a candidate to fill void left by luminiferous ether as a medium for light travel" this is completely within the classical framework and can be negated there. Introducing QFT in a nutshell is not necessary, imo .

Comment: @anna v, you are being stubborn and specious to no positive end. Even classically the EM field is a field, and fills all space by definition of "field," regardless of whether it has zero amplitude.

Comment: @user1247 Classically there exist an electric field  and a magnetic field, and they need a source. The electromagnetic manifestation is a wave propagating in space in specific loci. If I am being stubborn it is because I am defending the answer, which is a good and complete one with no need of invoking  QFT . I searched "classical electricity and magnetism " by Panosfsky  and Philips for "electromagnetic field" with 0 results. http://www.fisica.net/ebooks/eletricidade/PANOFSKY%20AND%20PHILIPS%20-%20Classical%20Electricity%20and%20Magnetism%202nd.%20Ed..pdf

Comment: @anna v, they don't need a source, are you aware of electromagnetic radiation? Do you know the definition of "field" when you say "electric field" and "magnetic field"? Of course these guys are frame dependent which is why one should even classically talk about the 4-potential and the EM-field rather than its frame-dependent components. This is stuff you should know, which is way this discussion is bizarre. Are you really trying to argue that "electromagnetic field" is a non-classical concept?

Comment: @user1247 This is getting ridiculous. We have a proverb in Greece "come grandfather let me show you your vineyards" . You are simply wrong that there exists a classical field for radiation in classical physics, which are self consistent theories until one hits dimensions of hbar. There exist electric and magnetic fields. And yes, you are carrying over a QFT definition of field which is unnecessary in answering this question.

Comment: @anna v, yes, ridiculous that you have too much pride for scientific and pedagogic honesty. I can quote from Jackson or Landau all day: "one should properly speak of the electromagnetic field Fuv rather than E or B separately." The electromagnetic field is absolutely mandatory given relativity, and has nothing to do with QFT. That said, it is completely specious to say that QFT is not "necessary" for answering the question. There are no "classical" qualifications made here. The question is about nature, and if QFT tells us something relevant about nature then so be it.